# Apache ProxyPass not working to remote host

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, apache, proxy

On remote machine 150.1.131.9 installed server with Django.
I can access to it with http://150.1.131.9:8000/
Want to access by kat.local

I was enabled mod_proxy in Apache 2.2
Added to vhosts.conf (imported to httpd.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Server name kat.local
ProxyPass / http://150.1.131.9:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://150.1.131.9:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

This don't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's not working exactly? Do you see an error? What do the apache logs show? What do you see in the django logs?

Comment: Note that [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) should give you what's needed to configure django for use with apache. You're not supposed to run django (`runserver`) behind apache.

Comment: It's opened another site which hosted on machine where Apache installed. No errors

Comment: you can't use `kat.local` as `ServerName` if you're accessing this remotely (unless this is the same network). also if it's serving another website, it means you probably have a `<VirtualHost _default_:80>` somewhere else in your *httpd.conf* file.

Comment: Checked httpd.conf, don't have <VirtualHost _default_:80>. On another PC setuped domain *some*.local. I was added domain name kat.*some*.local and ip to Django server It's works too access with kat.*some*.local but with port 8000. If I changed DNS to server with Apache, can I do ProxyPass?